# Boost interprocess message queue, open and close

Tags: c++, boost-interprocess

I have two processes, one write (create_only) and the other read (open_only). If the writer process is ending, i remove the queue. The reader however is able to carry on doing try_receive and doesn't raise exception or enable a notification. What's the recommended way of checking the existence of the queue, should i call get_max_msg or is there some other call in interprocess that i've missed?